# Android Studio Chipmunk (2021.2.1) Java 8 library desugaring in D8 and R8 Build Error: "Unsupported desugared library configuration version"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8

After updating my apps build gradle and dependencies (I did not update Android Studio itself), Android Studio is giving me this error: `Error: Unsupported desugared library configuration version, please upgrade the D8/R8 compiler.`
Before the update everything compiled fine.

I am using:

- `com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.0` (This was the newest version I could find)
- Gradle plugin version `7.2.0`
- Gradle version `7.5`
- Android Studio version `Chipmunk (2021.2.1)`

Did I configuration something wrong? How can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you got any solution for this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this page](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring), the minimum version of Android Gradle plugin required is `7.3.0-beta03` to be able to upgrade the desugar library to `1.2.0`, and `7.3.x` is not yet available for Android Studio Chipmunk.

Comment: it's 2.0.0 already but still only 1.1.5 version is supported by Android Studio

Comment: @user924 on Dolphin, and 1.1.5 is the only one that still works.

Comment: @user924 I'm using 1.1.6 on Dolphin. Works.